# Where did this "Done" button come from?

Tags: android

Android 2.35 - I have a multiline EditText on a screen which also has an OK and a Cancel button.   When the user finishes entering text he taps the OK button, which handles the inputted text.

When the Edittext is tapped in portrait mode the soft keyboard appears below the OK and Cancel buttons so it doesn't obscure them.   But in Landscape mode the soft keyboard covers the OK and Cancel buttons and a mysterious "Done" button appears to the right of the EditText - it's a plain button on a gray background.  Tapping it dismisses the keyboard.

I have no such button defined in my layout!   Where does it come from?   What determines its appearance, state, and properties?   Where are its events handled?   What is it called, so I can read more about it?

I tried adding

```
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

to my Edittext to give the soft keyboard a done button but it had no effect.  I'd rather have a "Done" button on the keyboard that looks like the rest of the keyboard than this weird "Done" button that doesn't look like or fit in with anything else on the screen.  Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: You didn't do anything - That's how android handles `EditText` in landscape mode. In landscape, editing a text happens fullscreen and the `Done` button is to signify that user is done editing and now can go back to the normal view.

Comment: So what determines its appearance?  It's a generic gray color and a generic system font so it doesn't go with either my layout styling or the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In landscape mode most IMEs go into fullscreen mode as the display is typically too small to show a meaningful part of the UI *and* the keyboard at the same time. You can kindly ask the editor not to do this by setting the flags `EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI` or `EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN`. This *may* work or not. But still it is up to you to test on as many devices as possible to see if this is still a good UX - often it is not.

Comment: Good explanation.  As an addition-  the reason the fullscreen edit UI exists is that in landscape mode on a phone, there's usually so little space left after putting up the soft keyboard that the UI is unusable.  That's why Android created it and uses it by default on phones.  Its also why it isn't usually the default on tablets-  the bigger screen means it isn't needed.

Comment: @his - thanks.  So what determines its appearance?  It's a generic gray color and a generic system font so it doesn't go with either my layout styling or the soft keyboard.   How do I style it?   Also, what is this called, so I can look it up in the Android documentation?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
```

and use  this class

```
class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```